# Difference between Setting Dependency Resolver and Extending Dependency Lifescope

Tags: c#, asp.net, autofac

I am reading the Autofac documentation related to its integration with OWIN, and I get confused by the example they put on their website:

```
public class Startup
{
  public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
  {
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    // STANDARD WEB API SETUP:

    // Get your HttpConfiguration. In OWIN, you'll create one
    // rather than using GlobalConfiguration.
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();

    // Register your Web API controllers.
    builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    // Run other optional steps, like registering filters,
    // per-controller-type services, etc., then set the dependency resolver
    // to be Autofac.
    var container = builder.Build();
    config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

    // OWIN WEB API SETUP:

    // Register the Autofac middleware FIRST, then the Autofac Web API middleware,
    // and finally the standard Web API middleware.
    app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
    app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
    app.UseWebApi(config);
  }
}
```

Where I am stuck now is on line `config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);` the webapi dependency resolver is set to autofac, and what is the reason that `app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);` must be called?

The extension method is to "Extends the Autofac lifetime scope added from the OWIN pipeline through to the Web API dependency scope", but the autofac lifetime scope is shared by setting dependency resolver, is this call still necessary?

It would also be very helpful if you can provide me the use cases of `UseAutofacWebApi`. Thanks!

Comment: what is the question? `app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);` is where you associate the `config` with the `app`, so that its setup in `app`'s request pipeline.

Comment: @YK1, my question is with `config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container)`, every dependency is able to be resolved when app start running, why do we need extra `app.UseAutofacWebApi(config)`? You mentioned it is a setup, what would happen without the setup? The code is working fine after I removed the `app.UseAutofacWebApi(config)`.

Comment: I reckon its a good question. As per [source](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.WebApi.Owin/blob/master/src/Autofac.Integration.WebApi.Owin/AutofacWebApiAppBuilderExtensions.cs#L27) it registers a message handler which adds `AutofacWebApiDependencyScope` to request properties, but without that line of code also, I see the `AutofacWebApiDependencyScope`  set in http request properties anyway. I guess more investigation is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is, yes, it's needed.

Usually a way to test this sort of thing is to see if you can get everything you need without it. I mean, if your app works and things are injected right, that's  enough, right?

The longer answer involves you needing to understand that Web API is not natively part of OWIN. OWIN is kind of a bolt-on. The way Web API integrates is, very basically, that the Web API pipeline is jammed into the OWIN pipeline as a middleware step. You can do other stuff with OWIN, too, like adding your own middleware and so on. It's a little beyond the scope of the question here to go through all the details of the ASP.NET pipeline, OWIN, how the middleware interacts, etc. A quick Google search for `how does web api work with owin` brings up a ton of documentation, blog articles, and explanations.

The important aspect there, though, is that there are basically two parts - the OWIN part, with its pipeline, and the Web API part, with its "sub pipeline."

Since the OWIN pipeline starts before the Web API pipeline, in order to make the two work together and have a request lifetime for the *whole* of the OWIN pipeline, you have to use the Autofac middleware to do that initialization. Then that same scope from the OWIN pipeline needs to make it into Web API. That also means when the Web API request is done, the OWIN pipeline needs to be able to handle the disposal of things rather than letting Web API handle it.

Hence the documentation: "Extends the Autofac lifetime scope added from the OWIN pipeline through to the Web API dependency scope." It's taking the scope created at the start of the OWIN pipeline and making sure it's the same scope that goes into the Web API pipeline.

Some applications not only have Web API but also ASP.NET MVC, all of which is trying to be coordinated through that OWIN pipeline and needing everything to work together. All of the stuff Autofac has in place to get Web API, MVC, and OWIN wired up is there for a reason - to make sure it all plays nicely together.

Generally if something is optional, the docs will explicitly say so. For example [in the Autofac Web API documentation](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/webapi.html) it's noted that it's optional to register filter and model binder provider handling. In this case, it's not really optional.

Comment: Hi @Travis Illig, thanks for your explanation. And the question I'd like to follow up is: on line `config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container)`, the lifetime scope of Autofac is introduced into webapi, is this redundant as Aufofac will take the scope created at the start of the OWIN to webapi? From my understanding, the webapi scope is set twice with essentially the same lifetime scope. Please correct me if I am wrong, thank you!

Comment: No, it's only initialized once. You need an adapter from Autofac lifetime scope to Web API lifetime scope, this is the adapter. You might want to take some time stepping slowly through the code - including the Autofac code (we have SourceLink support!) - if you have more questions as to when the adapters set things up and exactly what's happening when.

Comment: Also, if this answers the question, please accept it as the answer so I get credit for helping you out. Thanks!

Comment: @TravisIllig: Thank you for your answer. However, its very abstract. Could you give an example of source code which will _not work_ if we omit the line `app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);` ?

Comment: As noted, there is a lot to explaining how OWIN, Web API, and DI all come together. Getting into the details exactly is not something I can do here. Please take the time to dive into the code to understand how it works if you need specific answers and concrete info at that level. It's not complex code, but it does assume an understanding of all the concepts.